# Which list-element has been clicked in html (java servlet)

Tags: java, html, list, servlets

The problem is shown in the title.
Here's the code:

```
<div class=\"column-left\">
    <ul class=\"nav nav-list\">     
            <li tabindex=\"1\"><a href=\"BuyerSelectionPage\"><i class=\"icon-leaf\"></i> Ortaggi</a></li>
            <li tabindex=\"2\"><a href=\"BuyerSelectionPage\"><i class=\"icon-leaf\"></i> Verdure</a></li>
            <li tabindex=\"3\"><a href=\"BuyerSelectionPage\"><i class=\"icon-leaf\"></i> Formaggi</a></li>
            <li tabindex=\"4\"><a href=\"BuyerSelectionPage\"><i class=\"icon-leaf\"></i> Frutta</a></li>
            <li tabindex=\"5\"><a href=\"BuyerSelectionPage\"><i class=\"icon-leaf\"></i> Semi</a></li>
            <li tabindex=\"6\"><a href=\"BuyerSelectionPage\"><i class=\"icon-leaf\"></i> Succhi</a></li>
            <li tabindex=\"7\"><a href=\"BuyerSelectionPage\"><i class=\"icon-leaf\"></i> Piante</a></li>
            <li tabindex=\"8\"><a href=\"BuyerSelectionPage\"><i class=\"icon-leaf\"></i> Erbe</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It's a cut & paste from java, so don't look the \" instead of "

How can i catch it from a java servlet? Because i want to create dynamic pages querying a database instead of creating lots of static pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a parameter with href and check for value of this parameter using `request.getParameter("sel")`

Eg:

```
    <li tabindex=\"1\"><a href=\"BuyerSelectionPage?sel=1\"><i class=\"icon-leaf\"></i> Ortaggi</a></li>
    <li tabindex=\"2\"><a href=\"BuyerSelectionPage?sel=2\"><i class=\"icon-leaf\"></i> Verdure</a></li>
    <li tabindex=\"3\"><a href=\"BuyerSelectionPage?sel=3\"><i class=\"icon-leaf\"></i> Formaggi</a></li>
```